# Assigning URL String to Variable in Django

Tags: python, django

From what I can see there are 2 ways of using a string from within the URL. Either by using the URLConf or via request.GET.get.

Im trying to use the request.GET.get method and trying to capture the string after the = sign on a URL such as www.domain.co.uk/macoui=001100

**URLConf**

```
url(r'^macoui=\d{6}$', 'domain.views.output'),
```

**View**

```
def output(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       request.GET.get('macoui', '')
       return render_to_response('template.html', {'response': '\'%s\' % (macoui)}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I run this I get an error saying "nothing to repeat".

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few errors here.

You've correctly stated that there are two ways of getting parameters, then confused them both. If you're matching things in the urlconf, then you don't use request.GET to get them. Anyway, `request.GET` is only for querystring parameters - that is, URLs of the form `www.domain.co.uk/?param=value` where the `?` is the necessary part.

If your URL is really `www.domain.co.uk/macoui=001100` - without the `?` - then you need to fix your regular expression as follows:

```
url(r'^macoui=(?P<macaoui>\d{6})$', 'domain.views.output'),
```

and your view as follows:

```
def output(request, macaoui):
```

However, if - as is much more likely - your URL is `www.domain.co.uk/?macoui=001100` - with a question mark - then your URLconf should just be:

```
url(r'^$', 'domain.views.output'),
```

and your view becomes:

```
def output(request):
   macaoui = request.GET.get('macoui', '')
```

Comment: Thanks perfect answer. Big thanks to the other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem in this line:

```
{'response': '\'%s\' % (macoui)}
```

As you're escaping the last apostrophe and the entire string is never closed. You'll be better off using the other string delimiters:

```
{'response': "'%s'" % (macoui)}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You should simply do.

```
url(r'^/.*', 'domain.views.output'),
```

then use URL, www.domain.co.uk/?macoui=001100

URL on your example what not proper as get parameters (request.GET) on request uri are followed after '?'

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without URLconf with having the question mark ?